# How can I do "weighted" random number generation that favors some numbers over others, depending on user input?

Tags: c++, math, random, probability, weighted

First, I believe this is also maths based, so mods, if this is not the right place to address such a question, feel free to migrate it to a proper place. I am asking here, because I want this problem to be implemented in programming, specifically in c++.

Suppose the following scenario:
 - I want to RNG a number between 0 and 8
 - there is an extra input taking in factor to the number being generated, to give better odds to certain numbers in this way (I'll try to be as clear as I can) :

If the user inputs '0', the number to be generated will have the following chance to come out:

```
'0' - weight of 5,
'1' - weight of 4,
'2' - weight of 3,
'3' - weight of 2,
'4' - weight of 1,
'5' - weight of 0,
'6' - weight of 0,
'7' - weight of 0,
'8' - weight of 0,
```

So that the chance of getting a random '0' is 5 times bigger than getting a '4', and it's zero chance to get '5', '6', '7' and '8'.

If the user inputs a '4', then the weights are as follow:

```
'0' - weight of 1,
'1' - weight of 2,
'2' - weight of 3,
'3' - weight of 4,
'4' - weight of 5,
'5' - weight of 4,
'6' - weight of 3,
'7' - weight of 2,
'8' - weight of 1
```

In this case, all the numbers have a chance to come out, but favoring the number '4' to be generated.
Also, numbers '3' and '5' have the same chance of coming out, but yet, less probable than the number '4'.

And so on.

This can be translated into a weight table as the next picture shows:

[Table of Weights image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjUB2.jpg)

Considering that I made myself clear (if not, please tell me! I'll try to explain it in a better way) about the problem, how can the solution to this problem be designed?

I am tagging c++ because that's the language I am learning, but this can be applied to any language in general.

Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want `std::discrete_distribution`:

> `std::discrete_distribution` produces random integers on the interval `[0, n)`, where the probability of each individual integer `i` is defined as `w_i = i/S`, that is the weight of the `i`th integer divided by the sum of all `n` weights. [[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution)]

If your table is `std::vector<unsigned int> weights`, you can write

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::discrete_distribution<> d(weights.begin(), weights.end());
```

and then use `d(gen)` to get random numbers.

If the `weights` array has static size known at compile-time, you can use `std::array` with exactly the same syntax.

Comment: Oh man! Let me try that!! I'll leave some feedback an publish some test results.

Comment: I have some results that I published in a self answer. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be

Add all the weights according to the user input, 5+4+3+2+1+0+0+0 (sum=15) in your 1st example, 1+2+3+4+5+4+3+2+1 (sum=25) in the 2nd.

Choose a random integer in the intervall [0,sum-1]

Map according to your table, e.g. 0-4 => 0, 5-8 => 1 etc.

Comment: This is also a very good approach. I have to raise my math skills. I am also gonna try this way and publish some results.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing `std::discrete_distribution<>` as suggested by @Evg

I did this sample code that does exactly what I want!

No random_device because I am coding on Android...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {};
    std::cout << "Input vector size:\n";
    size_t vSize {0};
    std::cin >> vSize;
    v.resize(vSize);
    std::cout << "input max weight:\n";
    int maxWeight {0};
    std::cin >> maxWeight;
    std::cout << "Input the vector position for max weight:\n";
    int pos {0};
    std::cin >> pos;
    std::cout << "filling vector with weights...\n";
    for (int i {pos - 1}, j {0}; i < static_cast<int>(v.size()); ++i, ++j)
    {
        v[static_cast<size_t>(i)] = maxWeight - j > 0 ? maxWeight - j : 0;
    }
    for (int i {pos - 1}, j {0}; i >= 0; --i, ++j)
    {
        v[static_cast<size_t>(i)] = maxWeight - j > 0 ? maxWeight - j : 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Done.\n\nPrinting the array weight map:\n";
    for (int element : v)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
    using chrono_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    const auto seed {chrono_t::now().time_since_epoch().count()};
    std::mt19937 mt {static_cast<unsigned long int>(seed)};
    std::discrete_distribution<> rng(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << "- - - Generating 1 000 000 numbers: - - -\n";
    std::vector<int> numCount {};
    numCount.resize(vSize, 0);
    for (int i {0}; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        ++numCount[static_cast<size_t>(rng(mt))];
    }
    {//scope
        int i {0};
        for (auto element : numCount)
        {
            std::cout << "Number of '" << i << "'s: " << element << '\n';
            ++i;
        }
    }//scope
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And here is a sample run that matches the table I added in the question:

```
Input vector size:
9
input max weight:
5
Input the vector position for max weight:
5
filling vector with weights...
Done. 
Printing the array weight map:
1
2
3
4
5
4
3
2
1
- - - Generating 1 000 000 numbers: - - -
Number of '0's: 40032
Number of '1's: 79854
Number of '2's: 120201
Number of '3's: 160531
Number of '4's: 200083
Number of '5's: 159642
Number of '6's: 119873
Number of '7's: 80057
Number of '8's: 39727
```

It really was simple, but when you are just learning, things can look more complicated than they really are.

Regards!

Comment: You can use `std::abs` and `std::max` to merge two `for` loops into a single one: `for (auto i = std::max(0, pos - maxWeight); i < std::min((int)v.size(), pos + maxWeight); ++i) v[i] = maxWeight - std::abs(i - pos);` for zero-based `pos`.

Comment: Ohh, that's useful! Just curiosity, do you use c style casts for lazyness or is there any other reason?

Comment: Here, just to demonstrate the idea. `static_cast` is definitely a better choice.